# SAT Geometry Question

Tags: geometry

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PX7x.jpg

21) Answer: B. Pretty sure this uses the special 30, 60 triangle. But I am not sure how to create a right triangle from the picture that would help solve the length BC

32) Answer: 1976. Not even sure if I am on the right track but this is what I tried: I interpret what they are saying as a spherical hole being taken out from the cube and they are asking what is the mass of the just the metal. I first found the Volume of the sphere to be V= 4/3pi(4)^2 = 64/3pi. Multiply (64/3)pi(2.7)= 180.9 grams of aluminum. For the cube V= 1000. To find grams of cube 1000(2.7)= 2700 grams. I subtracted the grams of the sphere from the cube= 2700-180.9 = 2519.1

34) Answer: 2. I know the (h,k) would give the coordinates of the center of the circle B= (-2, -6). But I don't know what to do with the two intersection points they gave us.

EDIT: question 32, forgot to add pi for the sphere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

21) BCD is an inscribed angle to the diameter BD, so its size is 90. You know
one of the legs is r, and that the hypotenuze is 2r, so by Pythagoras you can conclude that the length of the other leg is sqrt(3)*r.

34) (-5,-2) is on both circles, so (x,y)=(-5,-2) has to satisfy the second circle's equation of (x+2)^2+(y-k)^2=25. You can determine k by substituting x=-5 and y=-2 and you get (-3)^2+(-2-k)^2=25.

Work it around a bit and you get 9+(-2-k)^2=25 ==> (-2-k)^2=16.

After you square root the equation, you get either -2-k=4 ==> k=-6, or -2-k=-4 ==> k=2 (since the square of both 4 and -4 is 16). If k=-6, then by the equation of the second circle you get that its center is (-2,-6), but that's the center of the first circle, so you conclude that k=2.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:  For  $21$

If angle $CAD$ is ${ 60 }^{ \circ  }$   then  angle $BAC$ is ${120} ^{\circ}$ degree   you can apply [Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)

Answer (score 0):

- If you look at $\triangle ABC$ (which is isosceles) and draw the altitude from $A$ to $\overline{BC}$, you get two congruent 30-60-90 triangles. The hypotenuse of each is $r$, so the long leg is $(\sqrt{3}/2)r$. the segment $\overline{BC}$ is twice the length of this long leg.
- When computing the mass of the removed sphere, you forgot the $\pi$ in your calculations. You also wrote the volume of the sphere incorrectly: the radius should be cubed.
  Anyway, the answer should be $(10^3 - \frac{4\pi}{3} 4^3)2.7$.
- Both $(-5,-2)$ and $(1,-2)$ must satisfy both equations. If you do some rearranging of the two equations, you can show $(y-k)^2 = (y+6)^2$ for $y=-2$. Thus $k=2$.

Comment: 1) Yeah, you're right I did forget the pi. Even so, I still don' get the right answer. (64/3)pi * 2.7 = 180.9 grams of Aluminum. Then it is 2700 grams of the cube - 180.9 grams of the sphere dosen't get me 1976 grams. Anything else I forget to add?

Comment: @Arcuvia See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

For $21$ you can use pythagorean theorem:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the picture, it helps a lot. Curious what/how were you able to write on the picture then save the edits? Did you use paint?

Comment: @Arcuvia, Yes I just copied the picture and open it in $Paint$, edit it, save it and then paste it here.